# Time series with multiple periods and non negative values

Tags: r, time-series

When I read time series in a `ts object` and put a period:

1. `tr <- ts(data[,4],frequency=)`. This works for two different periods and decomposes perfectly to show (downward) trend, seasonality and error. How do I know which is the correct period.
2. When I use a `ETS` or `STLF` function in the `forecast` package on the above ts object, the summary shows: Model Information: `ETS(A,N,N)` Why is that? We do have a seasonal+trend component here?
3. What can we do to deal with negative values when the training set is non-negative and negative values make no sense.

Comment: Has this question been answered sufficiently?  If so, can you mark it answered, please.

Answer (score 2):

1. What the correct period is depends on the data generating process.  For instance, if you are looking at monthly data driven by consumer habits, then, if we presume that consumer behavior fluctuates based on changing circumstances throughout the year, since the data is monthly, 12 is likely a good frequency to select.  It is important to keep in mind that periodicity is multiplicative.  If, for instance, 12 and 24 work, I'd go with 12.  If you have quarterly data, maybe 4 is a good frequency to select. Alternatively, if you are looking at some physical process, like the temperature in an engine, and you have millisecond data, maybe the appropriate period is the number of milliseconds per revolution.
2. The last two N's mean "none."  I am unable to tell why you think there is a seasonal component and ets does not.  From the help file:

   > Usually a three-character string identifying method using the
   >   framework terminology of Hyndman et al. (2002) and Hyndman et al.
   >   (2008). The first letter denotes the error type ("A", "M" or "Z"); the
   >   second letter denotes the trend type ("N","A","M" or "Z"); and the
   >   third letter denotes the season type ("N","A","M" or "Z"). In all
   >   cases, "N"=none, "A"=additive, "M"=multiplicative and
   >   "Z"=automatically selected. So, for example, "ANN" is simple
   >   exponential smoothing with additive errors, "MAM" is multiplicative
   >   Holt-Winters' method with multiplicative errors, and so on.
   >
   > It is also possible for the model to be of class "ets", and equal to
   >   the output from a previous call to ets. In this case, the same model
   >   is fitted to y without re-estimating any smoothing parameters. See
   >   also the use.initial.values argument.
3. What you do with negatives depends on the data generating process.  If, once the forecasted variable reaches zero, the process stops (i.e. you have an absorbing state), then maybe you can just set those foretasted values to zero.  If, however, you believe that downward movements become smaller and smaller, then you may have to change your model to reflect this.  Setting `lambda=0` would be a good start, which is equivalent to taking logarithms.  This would make the model multiplicative.  But, in general, if your forecasts are becoming negative and you know that is impossible, your model of the data generating process is probably wrong.

Comment: Thanks Prof for the detailed response. 
1) I think there is a daily as well as weekly periodicity in my data. I came across your paper on multiple periods and will make use of it. 
2) I used STLF. Is it not by default meant for seasonal data for periods more than 13? Is it possible I saw ANN because I had accounted for periodicity in the TS object

Comment: Defining the period in your TS object does not mean it will be ignored.  If, however, you inaccurately defined it, then maybe the state space model will not include a seasonal term.

Comment: As regards point 2), I feel there is a seasonality because I have added a frequency when I read the time series object. Also when I decompose the time series, I do get components. Please help

Comment: Also when I plot the series, I do see a seasonality. The data does show peaks and troughs on certain days of the year. BTW, I am using STLF function for the forecasting.